# don't fire OnExit event in stimulsoft

Tags: asp.net, report, stimulsoft

i use the stimulsoft webDesigner. when design reprort and click exit don't fire server side method

> .aspx

```
 <cc1:StiWebDesigner ID="StiWebDesigner1" runat="server"  OnExit="ExitReport" />
```

> code behind

```
protected void ExitReport(object sender, StiWebDesigner.StiExitEventArgs e)
    {
      //.....
    }
```

Comment: There is no Exit button in the Web Designer

Comment: exit button in stimulsoft->file->exit

Answer (score 0):

You should handle OnExit event on server side.